# Source of Vilna Gaon story with Sister

Tags: sources-mekorot, vilna-gaon

There is a [story](https://hevratpinto.org/tzadikim_eng/091_rabbeinu_eliyahu_of_vilna.html) said about the Vilna Gaon that:

> One day his sister (who he had not seen for years) came to pay a
> visit. When she entered his room, he greeted her and asked about her
> family. He then said, “My sister, we will see each other in the World
> to Come. There is no time here in this world. I have to study Torah.”

Where is the source for such a story?

Comment: I hope this story is not true

Comment: There's another story that he heard on Yom Tov that his sister died but he didn't react (because mourning is forbidden on Yom Tov) until bursting into tears right after Havdala

Comment: Also featured on the webpage: "Before his death, while crying abundantly, he confessed to having sinned in losing four minutes of Torah study." Perhaps that should be considered as well.

Comment: @kouty: it's worth noting an [essay](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=57474#p=365&fitMode=fitwidth) by R. A.Y. Kook of Rechovot, where he notes that such behavior would indeed be grossly inappropriate for most of us, but that for the Vilna Gaon it's different (see there).

Comment: The *nusach* I heard is that he conversed for a while with his sister and then stroked his beard and said, "You see, my beard is growing white, this is a sign *min ha'shamayim* that my days are numbered, I have to learn."

Comment: I always wondered...maybe he did not like her